# Использование Cron для запуска PHP с авторизацией

Tags: php, сессия, cron, ispmanager

Всем привет.
С какими параметрами мне запустить Cron, чтобы заработал PHP-скрипт, работающий только после авторизации? Проблема в том, что логин и пароль передаются не через адресную строку... Там происходит переадресация на страницу с формой авторизации и после неё уже возвращается на скрипт. Может быть я могу как-то указать логин/пароль прямо в параметрах Cron?
(используется ISPmanager 4.4 Professional)
Спасибо!

Comment: Обычно для cron скриптов не используется веб. И авторизация потому не нужна.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На сервере можно сделать так

```
*/15 * * * * php /home/test.php
```

Если не так, то нужно сохранить куку из браузера и использовать wget

```
*/15 * * * * wget -U="MOZILLA/5.0"--save-headers
-d -o log1.txt 
--load-cookies cookies.txt 
--keep-session-cookies \ -i file 
--cookies=on
```

Comment: это интервал крон задачи

Comment: @Lex_1992 Для начала запускайте команду в SSH консоли. Как только все заработает, можно добавлять задачу в crontab